# I am creating a cygwin silent install, howeer, the "make" package will not install

Tags: cygwin, make

I am creating a cygwin silent install,  howeer, the  "make" package will not install.

I only need the following:

"%CD%\setup-x86.exe" ^
--no-shortcuts ^
--no-desktop ^
--quiet-mode ^
--root "C:\cygwin" ^
--arch x86 ^
--local-install ^
--local-package-dir "%CD%\https_3a_2f_2fcygwin.osuosl.org_2f" ^
--verbose ^
--prune-install ^
--packages make,gcc-g++,gdb

No matter what combination of packages I list, "Make" will not install.

Please advise

Comment: It appears that the gdb package did not install either.  only the gcc-g++ package installed.

Comment: are you installing from a local cache ?

Comment: That is correct,  I downloaded the Cygwin packages and have then locally.

Comment: are you sure the make package is in the cache ?

Comment: Yes, because when I perform a manual install from the same source folder, I can seleck make and gdb, and both packages are installed.